# javascript toLocaleString not working in ie 9,10 and 11

Tags: javascript

I need to localize a number's string representation in browser. I am trying to use  `toLocalString` function. But it does not seem to work in IE(9, 10, 11).
My attempt at using it is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s_maksood/73jbLzLy/)

As per  [`msdn.microsoft` forum it should work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn412711(v=vs.94).aspx)

Can you help me identify where I am making a mistake?

For German Language, I am expecting following output: 123.456.789,00

However, in IE, i get the following output: 123,456,789.00

Comment: What is not working? What happens when you try? I get the same response in all my browsers using your example...

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Btw. Your fiddle seems to work in IE11.

Comment: @haxtbh updated question with details